# Deriving $\log{n} < \sqrt{n}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I make this claim in a proof I have written. I will like to prove this for my own sake.
How to proceed? I have actually seen this inequality a couple of times before,

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use calculus, then the following works:

Define $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ as
$$f(x) = \sqrt{x} - \log x.$$

Note that $f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} - \dfrac{1}{x} = \dfrac{\sqrt{x} - 2}{2x}.$

Thus, $f$ is increasing on $[4, \infty)$. As $f(4) > 0$, we have that $\log n < \sqrt{n}$ for $n \ge 4$.

The cases $n = 1, 2, 3$ can be verified separately.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x)=2\ln(x)-x$$
for $x>0$.

$$f'(x)=\frac{2-x}{x} $$

the maximum of $ f(x)$ is 
$$f(2)=2(\ln(2)-1)<0.$$

thus

$$(\forall x>0)\;\; 2\ln(x)-x\le 0$$
and
$$(\forall n>0)\;\;  \ln(n)-\sqrt{n}\le 0$$
$(n=x^2)$

Comment: What if calculus was not allowed?

Comment: @Xenusi Calculus is necessarily allowed in some extent because you can't define ln(x) without it.